# ORA-01722: invalid number error while executing select query on external table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I'm executing select * from owner_name.tablename; which is the external table having dat file.
while executing this it is not returning any rows and not even count(0) fetching results. I could see the below error in log file.

```
error processing column ID in row 1 for datafile /external/ab/output/user/table_name.dat
ORA-01722: invalid number
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
error processing column ID in row 140489 for datafile /external/ab/output/user/table_name.dat
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

But, the same *dat* file and same table executing fine in owner schema.

I did check all like *dat* file, DDL of table, file location, spaces in data file, delimiters and everything looking same but still error ORA-01722

What am I missing here? Previous *stackoverflow* questions are for insert queries and not for external tables.

DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE "OWNER"."TABLE_EXT" 
 (  "ID" NUMBER(22,0), 
    "SOURCE_CODE" NUMBER(3,0)
 ) 
 ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
  ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY "OWNER_EXT"
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    ( records delimited BY newline FIELDS TERMINATED BY "Ç" missing field VALUES are NULL
  (
  CLAIM_ID                  ,
  SOURCE_CODE               ,
  )        )
    LOCATION
     ( "OWNER_EXT":'table.dat'
     )
  )
 REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED 
PARALLEL 16 ;
```

DAT file :

```
Ç3Ç5278260051Ç557065100415Ç5278260051ÇÇÇÇÇÇÇ
```

Comment: You need to edit this question and post a [mcve].  external table definition, sample data

Comment: Have you looked at row 140489 in your table_name.dat file? The error seems to indicate whatever column you have referenced as `ID` is not a number. You can also try declaring ID in your external table definition, then try your query again and see if it works.

Comment: Can you expand on "But, the same dat file and same table executing fine in owner schema."

Comment: we have 2 schema which is OWNER and TEST schema, Same DDL and Same DAT file fetching results in OWNER schema. but, in TEST schema select query returns "error ORA-01722: invalid number error while executing select query on external table"

Comment: I suggest that you cut down your data file to lines just around the error line ( keep a few lines before and after) and retry in both schemas. You've done the right thing to check the log file. The next step in troubleshooting is to "shine a spotlight on the suspected data"